# How do I deallocate a single element of an array?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic, dynamic-memory-allocation

I allocate memory like this:

```
int *array = new int[n];
array[5] = 3;
```

and then assign values to it. However, I would like to free some space allocated by it in the meantime. I know that

```
delete[]
```

will deallocate the memory used by it, but I don't want the whole array deleted, but only certain elements, such as the first one, in order to implement a FIFO list. How can I deallocate the first element and then allocate space for a new element at the end of the array without deleting the whole thing? Can it be done with vectors instead of int?

Comment: In C++, if you ever think "dynamic array" then you next though should *always* be [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). And if you want a "FIFO" structure then [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue).

Comment: ***I don't want the whole array deleted, but only certain elements*** You can't do that. It's all or none.

Comment: I thought so, I'll stick to vectors then. Thank you!

Comment: I think you should move on a list ! there is plenty of samples about them and they are made for the purpose you are asking for .

Answer (score 1):

Once allocated, you can deallocate the memory in its entirety. Partial deallcoation is not possible. However, you may re-allocate another space with desired number of elements and then copy the earlier content to newly allocated ones and deallocate the earlier one. For example,

```
int *array = new int[n];
array[5] = 3;
std::vector<int> myvec(n1); // n1 is the new size
std::copy (array, array+std::min(n1,n), myvec.begin() );
delete [] array;
```

Comment: Or just use a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) - much easier.

Comment: Is it not possible to put a pointer to the element and then call "delete pointer"?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can implement FIFO by using a ring buffer: just introduce two variables: `first` and `last`, write new elements to `array[last % RingBufferSize]` followed by increment of `last` and read elements from `array[first % RingBufferSize]` followed by increment of first; when `first == last` it means that your FIFO is empty, when `(first + 1) % RingBufferSize == last % RingBufferSize` it means that your FIFO is full and you can't add without rejecting oldest item. With this approach you can use a static array and completely avoid using heap traffic.
2. Use [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) with keys taken from addition order (oldest first). With this approach, you'll have to grow allocated memory for your array only when it's getting overflown (that means "never" if your data source and data sink are working with the same speed and you need queue to damper the data stream). The binary heap itself has complexity about `log(N)` for addition and removal, which is much better than `O(N)` patching the hole in your array by copying it in a new array without an element being removed.